# Непонятная проблема с Android Studio монитором

Tags: android-studio

Появились проблемы с дебагингом приложений через Android Studio монитор.

Раньше запускал приложение, в мониторе пролетали системные записи связанные с запуском этого приложения, потом при запуске приложения я видел свои логи и если приложение падало, то ошибку с которой приложение упало. На выдаче ошибки поток сообщений заканчивался.

Сейчас монитор выдает сплошной поток какой-то ерунды и она выдается так быстро, что при падении приложения я даже не успеваю увидеть ошибку. Она просто теряется в потоке. **Может кто-нибудь объяснить, что это такое и почему этого раньше не было?**

Если полистать этот поток, то там полная бессмыслица. Есть строки с именем моего роутера и вай-фай сети. Есть строки с адресами из ДубльГиса. И другие непонятные штуки...

Может, я просто не знаю о какой-то настройке, позволяющий видеть только сообщения запущенного приложения? И она слетела?

Comment: Так везде. Приложения в своих сервисах или сама сисиема какает в логи всяким шлаком. Настройте фильтр на тэг `AndroidRuntime`

Comment: `AndroidRuntime` не нашел, но нашел в фильтре пункт `Show only selected application`. Видимо раньше он был выбран по умолчанию, поэтому я не видел этого потока. Спасибо за наводку.